# Solving a first degree equation - code optimization

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I have an equation which shows up like this:

[image: general equation]

where A and X are two vectors of numbers and N > 2 an user input (different each time) while G is a numeric constant and Y is the variable I'd like to find.
Making some computations, I'd say the solution might be generalized as follow (it's tested):

[image: general formula]

So here's my question. The code currently solving the equation is using a bisection method, i.e. it's estimating the value of Y by replacing in iterative way its value inside the formula until the global value of the expression is close enough to 0 (don't have access to the code, so I'm not able to say additional information about the break levels or its structure, unfortunately).

However, I was thinking about implementing a code calculating the code as shown in the solution (the second formula) above. This is my try:

```
num = 0
den = 0
For j = 1 To N
    prods = 1
    For k = 1 To N
        If k <> j Then
            prods = prods * X(k)
        End If
    Next k
    num = num + prods
    den = den + (prods / A(j))
Next j
Y = num / den
```

I have never studied any computer science, so I'm not able to assess myself the quality of this method w.r.t. the classic bisection one. 
Could anyone please give a tip about how I should understand which one of the two codes works better, and if possible some explanations? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** not being able to probably provide enough information for a proper analysis I do not expect any detailed result. I would just like to get the opinion of some experts "at first glance", being I'm not one of you :)

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using the formula `Y = sum_j (1 / X(j)) / sum_j (1 / (A(j) * X(j)))`?

Comment: The division into the bottom-sum is performed inside the sum itself, so I think the split you say is not feasible mathematically. Example with N = 2:

`y = [x(1)+x(2)]/[[x(2)/A(1)]+[x(1)/A(2)]]`.

Comment: I had the wrong formula in the first comment for less than a minute, but the one there now is obtained by dividing the numerator and denominator of your right-hand side by `product_j X(j)`.

Comment: Going out from the office, will get back to you asap. Thanks for your tip meanwhile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator of your solution by `product_j X(j)` to get the formula

```
       N
      ---   1
      \    ----
      /    X(j)
      ---
      j=1
Y = -------------- ,
     N
    ---      1
    \    ---------
    /    A(j) X(j)
    ---
    j=1
```

which can be evaluated straightforwardly in linear time, using about as many operations as it takes to evaluate the left-hand side of the first equation, which is the bulk of one iteration of bisection. Modulo the possibility of lurking numerical precision issues, I'd say that the direct method is superior to bisection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tested and realized you're right. For the way the data enter the function, I'd say your method needs N iterations only, cannot imagine a faster way!

Answer (score 1):

I get this solution from simplifications

[image]

which is solved for

[image]

With the trivial solution

```
Sub Main()

    Dim A() As Double, X() As Double
    Dim j As Integer, N As Integer = ...

    A = New Double(N) {...}
    X = New Double(N) {...}

    Dim num As Double = 0, den As Double = 0

    For j = 1 To N
        num = num + 1 / X(j)
        den = den + 1 / (A(j) * X(j))
    Next

    Dim Y = num / den

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you ja72, for sake of fairness I approved David's answer since he came first. Thank you!